# Which methods can be used to solve analytically an second order coupled ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve analytically an second order coupled ODEs?

As I know, firstly we can transform the 2nd order ODE to first order ODE and then it can be symbolically solved by using the Matrix method.

But I want to learn other methods.

Can you help me what are the methods and which books/notes do you suggest about it?

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf - also note that most times, you are stuck with numerical methods in the real world.

Comment: say you have coupled equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Sometimes it is possible to write this equation as a single one for $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$.